# Using Axios, how do you print url that caused an error?

Tags: javascript, node.js, axios

I have a function that provides utility for executing axios get. When an error occurs, I don't want to print the entire error. So I'm adding a custom message to the error message. The purpose of the custom message is to let me see what the actual request protocol, host, and path were used when the error occurred.

The following works for some errors, such as timeout or certificate issues

```js
this.axios
      .get(endpoint, { params, ...config})
      .catch((error) => {
        const customMessage = `\nFailed GET ${error.request._currentRequest.protocol}//${error.request._currentRequest.host}${error.request._currentRequest.path}`
        error.message += customMessage
        throw error
      })
```

The error.request is of type `RedirectableRequest` from follow-redirect.js and doesn't seem to provide anything other than the _currentRequest to get the data that I need.

However, for some other errors like 404 this works fine:

```js
const customMessage = `\nFailed ${error.request.method} ${error.request.protocol}//${error.request.host}${error.request.path}`
```

Here the error.request is a `ClientRequest`.

Feels like I'm doing something wrong. Any ideas what I can improve here? I cannot find anything on the internet, so maybe my setup is off?

I'm using axios 1.4, but the same issue is in 1.3.2

Comment: What's the issue? What's wrong with the code?

Comment: Did you try interceptors from axios?

Comment: I'll look into interceptors, but the problem is that sometimes I have to use:
`error.request._currentRequest.protocol`. Other times I have to use `error.request.protocol`. Seems really strange.